# Javascript input field onchage/oninput

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

Please help, how to make input like this in javascript?
Minimum number that can be entered = 0.01
Maximum number that can be entered = 94.99
if it passes the minimum/maximum it will automatically return to the default number for the minimum/maximum.
Meanwhile, if you enter the number 01.21, the number will automatically change to 1.21

Thanks for taking the time to answer, and provide direction.

[I want to create an input field similar to this](https://www.veed.io/view/74960dd8-5711-4874-95cc-6211ede6695a)

I tried like this but it doesn't work

```js
function minmax(value, min, max) {
  if (parseInt(value) < 0.01 || isNaN(value))
    return 0.01;
  else if (parseInt(value) > 94.99)
    return 94.99;
  else return value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="textWeight" id="txtWeight" maxlength="5" onkeyup="this.value = minmax(this.value, 0.01, 94.99)" />
```

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: I don't really understand where to start, so I'm just looking for some tutorials that don't fit

Comment: parseInt isn't going to work here since you're dealing with floats...

Comment: No need to convert numbers:
`minmax = (value, min, max) => value > min ? value < max ? value : max : min`

Comment: Please, can you write down the line of code so I don't get confused which one to edit

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't even need to use JavaScript for this, just plain HTML can solve your problem. The `input` tag has the [`min`and `max`properties](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp) that set minimum and maximum values for the input. Also, you could set the [`step`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_step.asp) of your input to 0.01.

This should solve your problems on the front-end. But note that this isn't enough to ensure that the data received by the back-end (if that's the case) is following your specifications, because malicious users can alter your page and send the data anyways, or even bypass the front-end completely. So, the back-end should also check if the data received is on the right format.

Comment: Maybe you mean by using input type number?
If yes, I have tried and due to my knowledge I don't get the number automatically changing if the conditions are met

Comment: You need to post some code.

Comment: I tried like this but it doesn't work

`<script type="text/javascript">
function minmax(value, min, max) 
{
    if(parseInt(value) < 0.01 || isNaN(value)) 
        return 0.01; 
    else if(parseInt(value) > 94.99) 
        return 94.99; 
    else return value;
}
</script>
<input type="text" name="textWeight" id="txtWeight" maxlength="5" onkeyup="this.value = minmax(this.value, 0.01, 94.99)"/>`

Comment: @MaruliDavin add the code to the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use [onchange](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event for this or add an [event listerner](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) to the input field and min, max to specify the maximum and minimum number.

```
<input id="input1" type="number" onchange="minmax()" min="0.01" max="94.99">
```

Then you can use javascript to compare the user entered value with min and max values using an if condition. If the user entered value is invalid simply replace the input field value with either min or max value!

Use [parseFloat()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) since you are dealing with floats.

```
function minmax() {
   let inp_field = document.getElementById("input1");

   let val = parseFloat(inp_field.value),
       min = parseFloat(inp_field.min),
       max = parseFloat(inp_field.max);

   if (val < min) {
      inp_field.value = min;
   } else if (val > max) {
      inp_field.value = max;
   } else {
      inp_field.value = val;
   }
}
```

And for the last part the [parseFloat](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) will automatically do that for you by clearing the leading zeroes.

Comment: Please, can this be converted into input type text or so that when the value entered is more it will change automatically following the minimum or maximum value

Comment: @MaruliDavin yes this will work for input type text

Comment: Amazing it works well! Thanks for writing clean of the code, You really saved my time.

Answer (score 0):

There are two event handlers `limitRange()` is bound to the input event and `keepDot()` is bound to the keyup event (set on capture, note the third parameter is `true`). `keepDot()` just handles the way Firefox refuses to accept the <kbd>.</kbd> key.

```
x.addEventListener('input', limitRange);
x.addEventListener('keyup', keepDot, true);
```

It has two jobs. First job is to limit input lower than .01 or higher than  94.99

```
this.value = +v < .01 ? '.01' : +v > 94.99 ? '94.99' : v;
```

The second job is to remove any leading zeros

```
 this.value = v.replace(/^0+/, '');
```

```js
const x = document.querySelector('#x')

x.addEventListener('input', limitRange);
x.addEventListener('keyup', keepDot, true);

function limitRange(e) {
  let v = this.value;
  this.value = +v < 0.01 ? '0.01' : +v > 94.99 ? '94.99' : v;
  this.value = this.value.replace(/^0+(?=\d)/, '')
}

function keepDot(e) {
  if (e.key === '.') {
    this.value = this.value + '.'
  }
}
```

```html
<input id='x' type='number' min='.01' max='94.99' step='any'>
```

Comment: this could be a good solution for input type number

Answer (score 0):

- call on `onchange` method
- `else return value - 0.01;` return float value
- `parseInt()`return integer value use `parseFloat()` return float valve
- `value - 0` remove useless 0 in value like `01.11` to 1.11`

```js
function minmax(value, min, max) {
  if (parseFloat(value) < 0.01 || isNaN(value))
    return 0.01;
  else if (parseInt(value) > 94.99)
    return 94.99;
  else return value - 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="textWeight" id="txtWeight" maxlength="5" onchange="this.value = minmax(this.value, 0.01, 94.99)" />
```

Comment: with this code when you fill in the numbers 0.1, 0.2 and so on... it automatically becomes 0.01 value. what I want is to be able to fill in 0.01, 0.02 and so on... only if it is smaller than 0.01 such as 0.001 it will automatically return to the minimum value = 0.01

Comment: @MaruliDavin check edited answer

Comment: Thanks, this also works well, but when I fill in such as 01.11 then there is no change, I hope that when I fill in such as 01.11 the value automatically changes to 1.11

Comment: @MaruliDavin check i edited answer input `01.11` output `1.11`

Comment: Thank you very much, you really helped me including increasing my knowledge. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hello thank you for question, the solution is simple try out once below code.

```
<input type="text" name="textWeight" id="txtWeight" maxlength="5" onkeyup="this.value = minmax(this.value, 0.01, 94.99)" />
```

Here you need to use [parseFloat()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) since you are using floating values.

```
function minmax(value, min, max) {
  if ((parseFloat(value) < 0.01 && value.length > 1) || isNaN(value))
    return 0.01;
  else if (parseFloat(value) > 94.99)
    return 94.99;
  else return value;
}
```